# How to reshape a data frame without using for loop in R or speed up the loop

Tags: r

In the following case, I need to split a column by given percentages and then reshape the data frame. Currently, I am using a for loop to do this. But it becomes too time-consuming for a large date set. Any solution to avoid a for loop or speed up the loop, please? Thank you.

```
library(plyr) # to use rename function

x = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b")
y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) # this col to be split by ratio in the next two cols
y_1 = c(0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1) # split ratio for y part 1
y_2 = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.2, 0.1, 0.9) # split ratio for y part 2

data_input = data.frame(cbind(x, y, y_1, y_2))

# Split y by ratios in y_1 and y_2

data_input$y_1 = as.numeric(data_input$y) * as.numeric(data_input$y_1)
data_input$y_2 = as.numeric(data_input$y) * as.numeric(data_input$y_2)

data_input # data to be reformatted

  x y y_1 y_2
1 a 1 0.5 0.5
2 a 2 0.8 1.2
3 a 3 0.9 2.1
4 b 4 3.2 0.8
5 b 5 4.5 0.5
6 b 6 0.6 5.4


# for loop to generate the output; taking too much time when there are millions of rows to split.
output = NULL

for (i in 1:nrow(data_input)) {
  
  print(i)
  
  placeholder = data_input[i, c("x", "y_1")]
  placeholder = rename(placeholder, c("y_1" = "y"))
  output = rbind(output, placeholder)
  
  placeholder = data_input[i, c("x", "y_2")]
  placeholder = rename(placeholder, c("y_2" = "y"))
  output = rbind(output, placeholder)
  
}

output

   x   y
1  a 0.5
2  a 0.5
21 a 0.8
22 a 1.2
3  a 0.9
31 a 2.1
4  b 3.2
41 b 0.8
5  b 4.5
51 b 0.5
6  b 0.6
61 b 5.4
```

***Update***

A follow-up question from the answer below. In the real data, there are 50+ more columns that I need to carry forward, i.e., copy them in all rows (**in the example, I only add one column z, but there are 50+ of z's in the data**). Based on the answer, it appears that I need to write out all of them. Is there a short cut to this?

```
x = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b")
z = c("s", "t", "p", "r", "q", "u") # note that there are 50 more columns like z; I only give an example here.
y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
y_1 = c(0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1)
y_2 = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.2, 0.1, 0.9)

data_input = data.frame(cbind(x, z, y, y_1, y_2))
data_input

data_input$y_1 = as.numeric(data_input$y) * as.numeric(data_input$y_1)
data_input$y_2 = as.numeric(data_input$y) * as.numeric(data_input$y_2)

data_input

data_input %>% pivot_longer(-c(x,z,y)) %>% transmute(x=x, z=z, y=value)

   x     z         y
   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1 a     s       0.5
 2 a     s       0.5
 3 a     t       0.8
 4 a     t       1.2
 5 a     p       0.9
 6 a     p       2.1
 7 b     r       3.2
 8 b     r       0.8
 9 b     q       4.5
10 b     q       0.5
11 b     u       0.6
12 b     u       5.4
```

Comment: `data_input |> dplyr::select(-y) |> tidyr::pivot_longer(-x)`? Or to replicate exactly (but for the row numbers, not sure if those important):  `data_input |> dplyr::select(-y) |> tidyr::pivot_longer(-x, values_to = "y") |> dplyr::select(-name)`

Comment: What do you mean by "carry forward"? Should they be like `x` in your original question draft, where one element in the input would translate to multiple rows of the output, or are they like `y_1` and `y_2` where each element only appears in one row or the output?

Comment: @JonSpring I updated my question with an example. In this case, col z should just be copied over.

Comment: `pivot_longer(-(x:y))` where x is the first column to leave alone and y is the last. Or you can specify by position `pivot_longer(-(1:3))` or in multiple groups `pivot_longer(-c(x:z, y))`

Comment: @JonSpring Could you show me the full code? I cannot seem to make it work by following your comment above. Thanks. `data_input |> select(-y) |> pivot_longer(-c(x:z, y)) |> select(-c(y_1, y_2))`

Comment: `data_input |> dplyr::select(-y) |> tidyr::pivot_longer(-c(x:z)) |> dplyr::select(-c(name))`. Btw, I would highly recommend taking any `plyr` usage out of your code. It's a retired package and has substantial naming conflicts with the actively supported, faster, more useful `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages, including common functions like `select` and `mutate`.

Comment: Sorry for that confusion. The mere purpose of the `transmute` function was to make the output look like you wanted it. To not have to name that many columns you can try `data_input %>% pivot_longer(c(y_1, y_2), names_to = NULL)`. And afterwards, if needed, you still can choose which columns to show with `dplyr::select` (as suggested by Jon).

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
library(tidyverse)
data_input %>% pivot_longer(-c(x,y)) %>% transmute(x = x, y = value)
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question based on your answers.

Comment: For n = 10k, the pivot_longer approach is approximately 2,000x faster (0.007 sec vs. 15 sec) and uses 8,000x less memory (1MB vs 9 GB). The gap expands with larger data as the OP method hits system limits.